# Output is given in 2 lines after concatenation of elements with odd and even indexes in a given string

Tags: arrays, ruby, split, concatenation

I wrote a function which takes all elements with odd indexes and concatenates them with all elements with even indexes in a given string n times:

```
def encrypt(text,n)
  while n > 0
    n -= 1
    str_array = text.split("")
    even_values = str_array.select.with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
    odd_values = str_array.select.with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }
    text = (odd_values+even_values).join
  end
  puts text
end

puts 'Type your message to encrypt:'
text = gets
puts 'Type number of times to run encryption:'
n = gets.to_i
encrypt(text,n)
```

The issue is that in case the input text has odd number of elements the function will return a text in 2 lines. At the same time if number of elements of input text is even the output is a 1 line text which is what I want.

Console output with 10 elements in input text:

```
Type your message to encrypt:
abcdefghij 
Type number of times to run encryption:
1
bdfhjacegi
```

Console output with 11 elements in input text:

```
Type your message to encrypt:
abcdefghijk
Type number of times to run encryption:
1
bdfhj
acegik
```

Comment: You need to chomp your input to get rid of the line break: `text = gets.chomp` the line break is being included in your joined string between the odd and even values when there are an odd number of chars

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `n = 1`

```
def doit(str)
  enum = [false, true].cycle
  str.each_char.partition { enum.next }.map(&:join).join
end
```

```
doit "abcdefghij"
  #=> "bdfhjacegi"
doit "abcdefghijk"
  #=> "bdfhjacegik"
```

---

For `n > 1`

```
n.times.reduce(str) { |s,_| doit(s) }
```

For example:

```
4.times.reduce(str) { |s,_| doit(s) }
  #=>"ejdichbgafk"
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`)

---

Now consider the calculations performed by `doit`.

First consider the enumerator `enum`, created with the method [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
 enum = [false, true].cycle
   #=> #<Enumerator: [false, true]:cycle>
```

We can use the method [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to see what values this enumerator `enum` will generate:

```
 enum.next
   #=> false
 enum.next
   #=> true
 enum.next
   #=> false
 ... ad infinitum
```

Now let's reset the enumerator using [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind):

```
 enum.rewind
   #<Enumerator: [false, true]:cycle>
```

---

Suppose

```
str = "abcdefghijk"
```

Then

```
e = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "abcdefghijk":each_char>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see what elements it will generate.

```
e.to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
```

Continuing,

```
a = e.partition { enum.next }
  #=> [["b", "d", "f", "h", "j"], ["a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k"]]
b = a.map(&:join)
  #=> ["bdfhj", "acegik"]  
b.join
  #=> "bdfhjacegik"
```

Note `a.map(&:join)` is shorthand for `a.map { |arr| arr.join }`.

See [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char), [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join).